# keypress.enter not working in RC.7

Tags: angular

Recently upgraded to rc7

I used `(keypress.enter)` as a handy event to capture enter event.
e.g.

```
<input (keypress.enter)="enter(thing.value)" #thing >
```

If used to work, but now it doesn't fire any event.
How can I make a custom directive to get only enter event, probably with same syntax.

Comment: When it worked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use ***keyup.enter*** instead

```
<input (keyup.enter)="enter(thing.value)" #thing >
```

**[Working demo (*in case you want with RC7*)](http://plnkr.co/edit/NrUanszzdQDGzi1tpuuM?p=preview)**

Comment: Are there any reasons for not implementing the same on keypress, as I can see it doesn't work even on released version

Comment: Working demo is no longer active :-(